# How to solve this natural logarithms problem?

Tags: logarithms

How do I take natural logarithm of the following?

$A - (Be^{-xy})$

Comment: Is your problem $A-(Be^{-xy})$ or $(A-B)e^{-xy}$?

Comment: It is A - (Be^-xy)

Comment: Is this part of an equation? Like the equation $A - Be^{-xy} = 0$?

Comment: The question is totally unclear. I have flagged it until this is made clearer.

Comment: Like this: $\ln(A-Be^{-xy}).$ There's really nothing else we can do with that, though.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yeah, that's what I was thinking. See my answer (you beat me by 27 seconds).

Comment: @AhaanRungta Flagging the question four minutes after it posted, without waiting just a tad longer for the OP to have a chance to clarify or respond to questions, is what I consider "jumping the gun." Give an OP the chance to respond!

Comment: @amWhy The OP saw our comments and refused to clarify, which is why I thought the clarification would never be made. But it seems you understood his/her question and have answered it and that's what matters! ;)

Comment: @AhaanRungta: Sometimes, new users take a bit longer to reply, or are unaware that they can edit their question. There is a difference between "refused to clarify" and "has not clarified yet." Try to be patient with them.

Comment: Sorry! I'll try to keep that in mind in future. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the equation shown below on the left hand side of $\iff$, we can do the following: $$A - Be^{-xy} = 0 \iff Be^{-xy} = A$$ Now we can take the natural logarithm of each side:

$$\begin{align} \ln\left(Be^{-xy}\right) & = \ln A \\ \\ \iff \ln B + \ln\left(e^{-xy}\right) & = \ln A \\ \\ \iff -xy & = \ln A - \ln B = \ln \left(\dfrac AB\right)\end{align}$$

Otherwise, if you are simply trying to take the logarithm of an expression, there's nothing you can really do to simplify the expression, so you'd have nothing simpler than $$\ln\left(A - B^{-xy}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. Sorry for being unclear, I really struggle with this topic. I hoped someone would understand.

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: The check looks lonely with out a TU +1

Comment: @Amzoti - not any more! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Until the question is made clearer, here is what I have to say. This is nothing you can do to simplify this further because it is $A-Be^{-xy}$, not $Be^{-xy}$ or $\frac{A}{Be^{-xy}}$. You cannot use logarithmic properties with such a form.